# JQuery to set global variable of dropdown menu value to be printed before title

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I'm trying to grab the value of a drop down menu and print it before the title of a section. In order to do that, I need to detect the change of the dropdown, grab the selected text, and print it to a global variable.

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#select_540', function(e) {
globalvar disMetalType = console.log(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

in the place I'm inserting it, I have this.

```
<h1 id="custom_product_name">
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.write (disMetalType);
</script>
<?php echo $_product->getNameCustom(); ?></h1>
```

I could use some help. I've asked previous questions on the same problem, but did some research, and tried a different angle of attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the intention is to have the selected option text appear within the `<h1>`. If that's the case, then why not within your `.on()` callback doing this:

```
var disMetalType = console.log(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
$('#custom_product_name span').text(disMetalType);
```

That requires changing your `<h1>` to be like this:

```
<h1 id="custom_product_name">
<span></span>
<?php echo $_product->getNameCustom(); ?>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems should use the following instead of document.write

```
jQuery('#custom_product_name').text(disMetalType);
```

Comment: You better check check what error pops out in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the insert as part of the code that triggers on change. THe document.write will only get called once the file loads, and no more after that.

So in your example:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#select_540', function(e) {
   globalvar disMetalType = console.log(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
   //find the element you are trying to change:
   $('#custom_product_name').prepend(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text + ' ');
}
```

To avoid the problem that will occur when someone changes the dropdown and have it repeatedly adding the value I would suggest changing the html to:

```
<h1 id="custom_product_name">
<span id="placeholder"></span> <?php echo $_product->getNameCustom(); ?></h1>
```

And then loading the id into the span:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#select_540', function(e) {
   globalvar disMetalType = console.log(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
   //find the element you are trying to change:
   $('#placeholder').html(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

Comment: I tried the second option, and it still did not work.

Comment: are you getting any console errors in Chrome or Firefox (F12)? Also is the console.log outputting the correct number?

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your title text depending on the selection of a dropdown menu. Please try the following: (this is just an example please change it according to your requirement)

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="white">white</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
<div id="title">this is the title</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#dropdown').on('change', function(){
    $('#title').html('this is the title : ' + $(this).val());
});
```